# Flex-wrap with equal width

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox

I use `flex-wrap` in CSS. I want a layout that accept these conditions:

- Use `flex-wrap`.
- Use the same width of all the boxes/child elements.
- Use the width of the largest child element. No fixed widths.
- It's not required to fill the width of the container.
- In the jsfiddle it would probably be 1 or 2 items on each row.

Is it possible with some clever css flex solution or do I need to use javascript?

https://jsfiddle.net/swysdq22/

```css
.wrap {
  width: 300px;
  background: #fff;
}
.narrow {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.narrow > * {
  background: #ccc;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="narrow">
    <div class="item1">
      Longest sentence.
    </div>
    <div class="item2">
      Short text.
    </div>
    <div class="item3">
      Another text.
    </div>
    <div class="item1">
      Longest sentence.
    </div>
    <div class="item2">
      Short text.
    </div>
    <div class="item3">
      Another text.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, this is not possible without JS. That's not the way flexbox works. At best you would get https://jsfiddle.net/swysdq22/1/

Comment: Maybe go for tables?

Comment: With js you could do https://jsfiddle.net/swysdq22/2/

Comment: @NenadVracar If it can't be solved with just css, this solution is probably the best one so far.

Comment: Just as a note if you want to use this spread operator is ES6 so you can see browser  compatibility here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator else you can do this https://jsfiddle.net/swysdq22/5/

Comment: @NenadVracar why don't you post it as an answer.

Comment: @Pangloss It's not tagged with js.

Comment: @NenadVracar Tagged it with javascript. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `map()` and `get()` to return array of widths and then with `Math.max` you can find maximum value in that array and apply it as width on each `item`

```js
var w = $('.narrow > div').map(function() {
  return $(this).width();
}).get();

var max = Math.max.apply(null, w);
$('.narrow > div').width(max);
```

```css
.wrap {
  width: 300px;
  background: #fff;
}
.narrow {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.narrow >* {
  background: #ccc;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="narrow">
    <div class="item1">
      Longest sentence.
    </div>
    <div class="item2">
      Short text.
    </div>
    <div class="item3">
      Another text.
    </div>
    <div class="item1">
      Longest sentence.
    </div>
    <div class="item2">
      Short text.
    </div>
    <div class="item3">
      Another text.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```